# How to convert brave.propagation.TraceContext to JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

Is there a way to convert the `brave.propagation.TraceContext` object to JSON?

I tried `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(traceContextObject)` but it gives `{"localRoot":true}`

Comment: I don't think `brave.propagation.TraceContext` is intended to be serializable but you can wrap the data you need into a POJO that you can serialize.

Comment: Yeah, I am doing that currently.